# Fast primality testing for very large primes

Tags: prime-numbers, pseudoprimes

I'm working on a project that requires me to find whether extremely large numbers are prime numbers or not. Of course, I've read how to find prime numbers and have come up with a very simple brute force method:

```
def is_prime_brute_force(p):
    if p == 2 or p == 3:
        return true
    if p == 1 or p % 2 == 0 or any(p % i == 0 for i in range(3, floor_sqrt(p), 2)):
        return false
    return true
```

I've also investigated such probabilistic methods as the [Miller-Rabin Primality Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test#Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_and_Solovay%E2%80%93Strassen_primality_test) and Fermat's little theorem (see [here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test#Python) for Rosetta code's implementation of the former).

Though the probabilistic options are an order of magnitude faster than brute force, they're still very slow for very large inputs of `n` (for example, the known prime `10**9999 + 33603`).

I came across an interesting observation (of course I'm not the first to come across such an observation) that **all** primes fit the equation $p = 6k \pm 1$. In Python, such a function looks like this

```
def is_prime_eq(p):
    if p == 2 or p == 3:
        return True
    if p == 0 or p == 1:
        return False

    # The same as `return (p % 6 == 1) or (p % 6 == 5)`
    prime_test = lambda p, a, m : (p % a == m) or (p % a == (a-m))
    return prime_test(p, 6, 1)
```

The above is guaranteed to return true if `p` is a prime, but a true result does not mean the `p` is a prime. An easy example is 25 ($25 \equiv 1\ (mod\ 6)$, but clearly $25 = 5^2$).

I'm wondering if there's some more general way to apply this interesting property of primes, perhaps with different values of `a` to improve the speed of my `is_prime` function.

Comment: "return true" is faster and almost as accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, note that your "brute force" algorithm has some errors.  It should be:

```
def is_prime_brute_force(p):
    if p == 2 or p == 3:
        return true
    if p == 1 or p % 2 == 0 or any(p % i == 0 for i in range(3, floor_sqrt(p), 2)):
        return false
    return true
```

In relation to this algorithm, your proposed "faster" algorithm is equivalent to

```
def is_prime_brute_force(p):
    if p == 2 or p == 3:
        return true
    if p == 1 or p % 2 == 0 or p % 3 == 0:
        return false
    return true
```

Hopefully you see why this is not terribly helpful.  Any composite which is a product of primes $\geq 5$ will evaluate as a prime.  Usually we use probabilistic primality tests (e.g. Miller-Rabin) for numbers whose prime divisors are all sufficiently large, so ignoring all prime divisors greater than $3$ makes it fairly useless.  It's for this reason I facetiously proposed

```
def is_prime_brute_force(p):
    return true
```

in the comments as a much faster algorithm that doesn't lose much accuracy.

---

Primality tests are by their nature rather costly on current hardware.  The best you can do is to try to optimize for some given assumptions on the input.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out those errors in brute force! I've adjusted the question to reflect them.

Answer (score 1):

If we do not demand a rigorous primality test, the Miller-Rabin test is one of the best tests currently known. Very reliable is a shortcut called BPSW-test. Complete trial division is of course infeasible for huge numbers, but it is reasonable to rule out small factors before the test.

If the number is huge, a proof of the primality will only be feasible, if the number has a special form.

But even if we only apply a single weak Fermat test, the complexity is not better than $O(\ln(n))$. Apart from applying trial division upto a reasonable limit before the primality test, you cannot do any better with the currently known methods, as Brian already pointed out.